# таймер в java GUI

Tags: java, swing

таймер каждые 100 милисекунд должен дописывать пятерку, но он этого не делает

```
package com.javacodegeeks.example;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class Calculator {
  private JTextField resultsTxt;
  private JButton SetBtn;
  private JPanel calculatorView;
  private JTextArea textArea1;
  public Calculator() {
    SetBtn.addActionListener(new SetBtnClicked());
  }
  private class SetBtnClicked implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      String a, s;
      a = resultsTxt.getText();
      s = textArea1.getText();
      textArea1.setText(s + " " + a);
    }
  }
  javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      textArea1.setText(textArea1.getText() + " 5 ");
    }
  });
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
    frame.setContentPane(new Calculator().calculatorView);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: у вас программа в корне **неверна** и с кучей ошибок - контекстная панель не создана, а просто объявлена, в нее не помещена кнопка, тайме, jtextarea тем более. Такое ощущение, что вы просто набросали все овощи в тарелку и спрашиваете как сделать оливье.

Comment: @кузьмич а где у вас инициализируются переменные типа панель и текст?

Comment: а как это сделать? я форму делал по уроку из интернета

Comment: какова цель вашего урока? Таймер, который будет добавлять в `textArea` каждые 0.1 с. по "5" в конец?

Comment: да, это цель урока

Answer (score 2):

Тогда внимательно посмотрите ваш урок ещё раз. [Здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) можно посмотреть хорошие примеры, как делать приложения с использованием `Swing`. А вот простой пример с [использованием таймера](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590285/using-java-swing-timer-to-process-and-append-text-into-textarea), который добавляет в конец `JTextArea` каждый раз цифру "5":

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator"); // создаём фрейм нашей программы

        JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(); // создаём панель, на которой будет лежать текстовое поле
        JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();

        mainPane.add(textarea); // добавляем на панель

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textarea.append("5"); // ставим задачу - добавлять пятерку в textarea
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer( 100, listener ); // ставим задачу на таймер на каждые 100 милисекунд
        timer.start(); // запускаем таймер

        frame.setContentPane(mainPane); // кидаем панель в JFrame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]